# Adding lambda permission - AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I have created a lambda function using terraform to access AWS secrets manager and rotate the secrets. Below I have listed the resources. I have followed every aws doc to fix the error but still no clue.

Here are the IAM resources:

```
# Secret rotation lambda execution role
resource "aws_iam_role" "secret_rotation_lambda_execution_role" {
  name = "secret_rotation_lambda_execution_role"
  description = "Execution role for secret rotation lambda"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

# Policy for AWS Secrets Manager to invoke the secret rotation lambda
resource "aws_iam_policy" "secrets_manager_policy" {
  name        = "secrets_manager_rotation_policy"
  description = "Policy for AWS Secrets Manager to invoke the secret rotation lambda"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = [
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
          "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue",
          "secretsmanager:RotateSecret",
          "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret",
          "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
          "secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
        ],
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = [
          "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ]
        Resource = "arn"
      },
    ]
  })
}

########################
# Secret Rotation Lambda Policy Attachment
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "secrets_manager_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.secret_rotation_lambda_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.secrets_manager_policy.arn
}
```

Lambda function:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "rotation_lambda" {
    
    function_name = "RotationLambda"
    filename      = ""
    role          = aws_iam_role.secret_rotation_lambda_execution_role.arn
    handler       = "FunctionHandler"
    runtime       = "dotnet6"
    timeout       = 60
    memory_size   = 256
    description   = "Lambda for secret rotation for secrets stored in secrets manager"

    source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("zips/file.zip")
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_rotate_secrets_permission" {
    statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSecretsManager"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "RotationLambda"
    principal     = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = "arn"
}
```

Secrets manager:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" "secret" {
    secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.id
    rotation_lambda_arn = "arn"
    rotation_rules {
        automatically_after_days = 30 
    }
    depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_rotate_secrets_permission]
}
```

Error:

```
Error: adding Lambda Permission (arn/AllowExecutionFromSecretsManager): AccessDeniedException: 
status code: 403, request id: 87d534cd-0d08-4d60-bddf-4d5b2b08ccf3
```

I'm not sure why this error is coming, I've tried many ways to fix it but still clueless.

Comment: The environment in which the terraform deployment is running does not have sufficient permissions

Comment: In your `aws_lambda_permission` which resource is the ARN for in `source_arn`?

Comment: @GlenThomas Secrets manager secret arn